# Convert ruby array to java script array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

I have a ruby code that will generate an array.I need to use that array in javascript.

```
<%= region.zip(min, max).select {|_, a, b| a == '0' && b == '0'}.map(&:first)%>;
```

This above code will generate an array like this

```
["A", "B", "C", "F", "H"]
```

Here is the demo http://repl.it/t03/680

I want to use this array in javascript. Below is what I tried and the error I got in console.

```
<script>

 var output = <%= (region.zip(min, max).select {|_, a, b| a == '0' && b == '0'}.map(&:first)).gsub('"', '') %>;

</script>
```

Error is

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&'

var output = [&quot;A&quot;, &quot;B&quot;, &quot;C&quot;, &quot;F
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually jeremy answer after modification.

```
 var output = <%= raw(region.zip(min, max).select {|_, a, b| a == '0' && b == '0'}.map(&:first).map{|item| item.gsub('"', '')}.to_json) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON is technically valid Javascript, so you could do something like:

```
 var output = <%= (region.zip(min, max).select {|_, a, b| a == '0' && b == '0'}.map(&:first)).map{|item| item.gsub('"', '')}.to_json %>;
```

And that should work as expected.

**Note:** I added the `.to_json` at the end of the Ruby code.

Comment: I tried ..got this error
undefined method `gsub' for ["A", "B", "C", "F", "H"]:Array

Comment: Try removing the `gsub(...)`. I think this is not actually needed.

Comment: Alternately, if your strings still have quotes in them you'd like to remove, you could run `gsub` inside another `map`. The reason you can't `gsub` on the whole array is because `gsub` can only be called on individual strings. So maybe you instead want to do something like `...).map{|item| item.gsub('"', '') }`

Comment: sorry..updated solution dint work..getting the original error

Comment: Ok, well then if all else fails, you can try wrapping the whole thing in `raw(...)` which should stop it from escaping the quotes.

`var output = <%= raw((regi...', '')}.to_json) %>;`

Comment: But, you should avoid using `raw(...)` unless you can be sure that the strings will not contain anything that looks like `</script...` because this could result in some kind of injection error. This should be fine if you have supplied the strings yourself, but if they are user-supplied, you should use another method, such as placing the JSON in an HTML DIV, and then accessing it by calling `JSON.parse($('#my-div').html())`

Answer (score 1):

I used to do in the "standard" way, writing JS storing JSON in a variable, now I highly recommend to use: [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon)

It's great and allows you to handle with this situation easily, in your controller type:

```
gon.push({variable_name: [1,2,3]})
```

In your app layout use:

```
<%= include_gon %>
<!-- include your action js code -->
```

In your js you can just type:

```
console.log(gon.variable_name) // [1,2,3]
```